# delete records from mongodb collection after skip by beanie ODM

Tags: mongodb, fastapi, pydantic

I want to delete some records after sort and skip items but this query always delete all records after find.as if sort and skip don't do anything':

```
await Book.find(Book.owner.id == user.id).sort("-created_at").skip(2).delete()
```

Comment: Hey delete is not an available function, so your query would throw an error rather than deleting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the target you can first fetch the docs by applying a skip function & then use deleteMany function.

**Note:** You can also use sort({_id:-1}) to sort the docs.

**See the Example code below-**

```js
const data = await Book.find(pass-your-query-here).sort({_id:-1}).skip(2);
        if(data.length>0){
          const ress = await Book.deleteMany({ _id: {$lte: data[0]._id } });
        }
```

Comment: thank you. 
I get idea from your answer and do it by beanie syntax.

Answer (score 0):

We can delete the items by beanie functionality like this:

```
from app.models.book_model import Book
from beanie.operators import In

books= await Book.find(Book.owner.id == user.id).sort("-created_at").skip(2).to_list()

books_del= Book.find(In(Book.id, [_.id for _ in books]))
await books_del.delete()
```